# Is men kissing men haram?

Tags: homosexuality, kissing

I am attracted to men (I am a boy). There is an attractive boy in my school and I can’t even speak to him. When he passes by me, my heartbeats go to the highest level.
I love him and can’t spend only a second of my life without thinking about him.

Now I want some guidance that what should I put on this bad situation.
Is kissing haram? (Male and male)

Comment: shows absolutely no research effort.

Answer (score 3):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, the Most Kind.

**Answer:**

Firstly:

I understand you well, and this is a devil’s whispers and Homosexuality is a big crime inherited from the people of LUT. Because of the enormity of this sin, a severe punishment struck them.
I think it is a test from God Almighty, and I suggest you ask forgiveness from God because He Says:

> ”And God does not burden a soul with more than it can bear.”

My advice for you is to ask God Almighty to forgive you because God Says:

> ”O you who believe! Turn to God with sincere repentance!” [Quran, 66:8]
>
> ”And beg God to forgive you all, O believers, that you may be successful.” [Surah An-Noor, 31]
>
> ”Truly, God loves those who turn unto Him in repentance and loves those who purify themselves.” [Quran, 2:222]

Also, try your best to do more good deeds because God Almighty Says:

> ”Except those who repent and do righteous deeds, and openly declare (the truth which they concealed). These, I will accept their repentance. And I am the One Who accepts repentance, the Most Merciful.” Quran, [2:160]

And my final advice for you is, try your best to ignore this feeling that you have and pray a lot. Recite the following verses:

1) The Throne Verse( Ayat al Kursi)

2) The Cow( Al Bakara)

And think of God always, fear Him a lot, remember the story when God Almighty saw the people of Sodomy they were committing the worst sins ever and God punished them, keep saying to yourself: “I am much better than those who lived in the city called Sodomy”, be more occupied on your studdings and on how to do more good deeds and be more occupied with Islam and think of how to make God be happy with you.

I hope that this is a good answer. If there’s anything wrong in here, please let me know.

And God knows best.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                    In the name of Allah
```

Uh, @mate, based on what you have illustrated, as you probably agree with that, it could be related to the negative thoughts or actually to satanic feelings. There would be some different points as solution for you, which I name some of them.

- Recite the following Zikr (several times) whenever you are thinking
  about that.

> ```
>                             اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم
> ```

- Endeavor not to place in the locations which leads to see or
  encounter him … , and try to looking at other places in order to
  prevent looking at him …
- Endeavor to make yourself busy by different acts (such as talking
  mobile phone, your class-mates, and so on) whenever your mind in
  thinking about that.
- Finally, don’t forget that those kinds of thoughts can be counted as
  haram thought (as sins in your “report card, in Doomsday!”, besides,
  it seems that you are a good and pretty religious guy who have asked
  such question in order to find a good solution in order to get rid of
  that sinful situation. Therefore trust Allah, and don’t forget the
  Zekr of اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم

Concerning your last question, concerning kissing of male (to male), it would be permissible in normal form of that in the greetings. But dear mate, it is just permissible in normal condition. Namely: in a normal form as it is done as a custom in Islamic countries..., not in the way of kissing with sinful thoughts in mind. Thus kissing male to male would be haram if it is done with negative and bad intention such as enjoyment… (Even in the mind).

---

**Reference:**

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa10258)

Comment: it should be more elaborated as kissing male to male is not allowed except on cheeks without desire as it is a custom in mostly Arabs but it is disliked and should be avoided.

Comment: Yeah, It is an important point as you pointed out "it should be more elaborated as kissing male to male is not allowed except on cheeks without desire as it is a custom". / Of course I meant it is OK if you do it at custom ... (by saying " it is just permissible in normal condition"). /// I'll edit it not and add what you stated more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In The Qur'an it is described as the worst sin committed such as none preceding you has committed in the 'Aalameen  (mankind and jinn)

Allah says (meaning):
"And (remember) Loot (Lot), when he said to his people: ‘Do you commit the worst sin such as none preceding you has committed in the ‘Aalameen (mankind and jinn)?

Verily, you practise your lusts on men instead of women. Nay, but you are a people transgressing beyond bounds (by committing great sins)’”
Surah al-A’raaf 7:80-81

“Verily, We sent against them a violent storm of stones (which destroyed them all), except the family of Loot (Lot), them We saved in the last hour of the night”
al-Qamar 54:34 – [meaning]

“And (remember) Loot (Lot), when he said to his people: ‘You commit Al‑Faahishah (sodomy the worst sin) which none has preceded you in (committing) it in the ‘Aalameen (mankind and jinn)’”
al-‘Ankaboot 29:28 - [meaning]

It is a great evil. From these surahs and many more places we can see that it's something which gains Allah's curse and gains a severe punishment. It's something we should completely avoid even if it means changing school so you don't see that boy again.

These tips may also help:

1. feel regret for such thoughts/feelings and seek Allah's forgiveness and repent to Him against this and ask for His help to remove such thoughts and temptations
2. seek refuge against the shaitaan, listen to Surah Al Baqarah daily at home, recite the last 3 surahs 3x morning and evening daily (Ikhlas, Falaq and Naas)
3. recite Ayatul Kursi once after every prayer and 3x morning and evening and once before you go to bed
4. when leaving the house in the morning for school say "Bismillah" and when entering your house say "Bismillah".

I saw something on the internet a while ago where every time this person committed a sin (caused by the Shaitaan) they prayed 2 rakahs of sunnah (optional) prayer. Every single time they committed a sin they would immediately follow it up with 2 rakahs of optional prayer and then the shaitaan stopped wanting them to sin because he knew by getting this person to sin they would then pray to Allah and he doesn't want us to pray to Allah so then the person stopped committing sin. A similar thing might happen with you in this situation; every time you have the evil temptation immediately pray 2 rakahs of sunnah prayer every single time you never know it might change things for the best in shaa Allah.

May Allah make things easy for you and all of us. Ameen.

Answer (score -1):

Recite astagfar
And
In quran Allah says
ان النفس لامارہ الا ما رحم ربی
Allah forgive me if i wrote wrong
So  recite
رب اغفر وارحم و انت خیر الراحمین
Very powerful
My shykh told me these ...
May Allah help u i pray for you....
We can recite Quranic duas oueselves
Or u can tell a scholar or a Shykh about this and take permission for these zikr..  or do what Shykh tells u...
Pray for me... I pray for u...
السلام علیکم

Answer (score -1):

It's not haram. What is haram is sexual exhibitionism. Remember that the Qu'ran enjoins modesty in how one behaves and dresses in public.